# C# Get a BitmapImage Height

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

When I create a BitmapImage, the Height parameter gives me the... width. 
Here's my code, if you see the error, I can't.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Bitmap files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName));
            int maxHeight = 100;
            if( image.Height != maxHeight)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error with the size");
                return;
            } 
            FileTextBlock.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            ImageWPF.Source = imageEndo;
        }
    }
```

Tried this with a bitrmap image with 100 height, and 16 width, got 16 in image.Height.

Comment: Use PixelHeight instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.pixelheight(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Working ! Thank you !

Comment: No problem, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rand Random, I solved my problem with the PixelHeight instead of Height.